# CodeIgniter DataMapper get_iterated

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

Can someone please provide an explanation of the difference between `get()` and `get_iterated()` in the context of CodeIgniter's DataMapper ORM referenced here:

http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/getalt.html#get_iterated

I've read through it multiple times, but do not understand.  I've also output the result of queries using each method, but don't see the difference.  I can confirm that `get_iterated()` definitely uses a lot less memory than `get()`, but I would like to understand what's actually happening.

I'm hoping someone can provide a clear explanation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the implementation of `get_iterated()` (comments mine):

```
public function get_iterated($limit = NULL, $offset = NULL)
{
     // get hold of object after it is cleared though call to get_row
    $object = $this->get_clone();
    // clears the query from the clone
    $object->db->dm_call_method('_reset_select');
    // clear the related query from the clone
    $object->_query_related = array();

    // REAL MAGIC starts here: Build iterator
    $this->_dm_dataset_iterator = new DM_DatasetIterator($object, $this->get_raw($limit, $offset, TRUE));
    return $this;
}
```

The real magic happens at the line:

```
$this->_dm_dataset_iterator = new DM_DatasetIterator($object, $this->get_raw($limit, $offset, TRUE));
```

The real speedy work is done by the `DM_DatasetIterator` class for the `get_iterated()` method because it implements an `Iterator` ***which are generally FAST***. The class implements all the required methods that are required by the `Iterator` interface such as `current()`, `key()`, `get()`, etc

So overall there are two reasons why it is fast:

- The actual object is cleaned (query and related info)
- It is then passed to iterator which are fast

You might ask why iterators are fast? Well because **they process data iteratively instead of buffering in memory**.

Learn about here:

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php